# How to find the lowest numbered computer on a network

Tags: powershell

I am attempting to write a script to copy some information from one computer to another. The first computer has a name similar to "SERVERxx" where xx is the site number. There are multiple computers on the network with names similar to "TERMINALxx_yy", where xx is the site number and yy is the number of the TERMINALS. What I would like to do is find the lowest numbered of the "TERMINALS" (as 1 may not always  be the lowest). There is an environment variable on the SERVER named TERMSTR that is equal to "TERMINALxx_", as well as an environment variable named NUMTERMS that is the number of TERMINALS at the site.

The most I've been able to figure out is:

```
net view | Select-string $termstr
```

But that just gives the table output.

I'm figuring I need to first have `NET VIEW` give just the computer names, then sort in descending order and select the first one.

Thanks

Comment: In a Windows environment, investigate `Get-ADComputer` and `Test-Connection`.

Comment: That won't work as ````Get-ADComputer```` is not installed on these machines.

Answer (score 0):

if you absolutely MUST use `net view`, then this will give you the <s>highest</s> lowest system number with the header, footer, line padding, and non-digits removed. it does not add any leading zeros to the resulting number, tho. [*grin*]

```
net view |
    # skip the 3 header lines
    Select-Object -Skip 3 |
    # skip the footer lines
    Select-Object -SkipLast 2 |
    # trim away the "net view" line padding
    # remove the non-digits
    ForEach-Object {
        [int]($_.Trim() -replace '[^0-9]')
        } |
    Sort-Object |
    Select-Object -First 1
```

Comment: It doesn't have to be ````NET VIEW````. Is there something else that would be easier.

Comment: @Harlan - the AD stuff is the better choice, but you say that it is not available. so take a look at the `[adsi]` stuff since that WILL be on any system with reasonably up-to-date dotnet stuff installed. [*grin*] ///// however, if `net view` does the job ... well, you may want to stick with that. my personal inclination is to go with the more flexible, object oriented stuff that you will get from `[ADSI]` - but that is a personal preference.

Comment: What would be the ADSI "stuff"?

Comment: @Harlan - from a quick net search, i found this nifty article [*grin*] >>> Active Directory PowerShell with ADSI - Petri — https://www.petri.com/active-directory-powershell-with-adsi <<<

Answer (score 0):

Here is a starting point of code you can use.

```
$Servers = Get-ADComputer -Filter 'Name -like "SERVER*"' 
foreach($Server in $Servers | Sort-Object){
     $N = $Server.name.substring(($Server.name.length)-2)
     $Terminals = Get-ADComputer -Filter 'Name -like "TERMINAL$($N)*"'
     $count = $Terminals.Count
     $Terminal = $Terminals | Sort-Object
     $TerminalZero = $Terminal[0].Name
     Write-Host "Terminal Name: $TerminalZero"
     $COMMAND = {
     Write-Host [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("termstr","Machine")
     [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("TERMSTR", $TerminalZero, "Machine")
     [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("NUMTERMS", $Count, "Machine")
     }
     Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Server -ScriptBlock { $COMMAND }
     }
}
```